# What is the best way to collect the relevant fields for a UI screen?

Tags: user-story, requirement-gathering, ux-research

I understand that most of this data comes from the user story/use case/PRD etc.
But how do we make sure that the fields (KPIs/Status/Properties/Charts etc) that we display are the ideal ones for the user?

The reason why am confused is user story is typically drafted by Product Owners or Business Analysts. They may draft it from their own perspective which may or may not be what the users are interested in. What is the general practice?

Answer (score 3):

Stories should be based on user research. If they are not, spend some time in research to understand what common tasks are users trying to accomplish in the page and how are they doing it. Derive learnings from the research and modify the stories accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this situation is to create multiple variants:

- one with following exactly the directions of the PRD
- and one or more versions that are based on my ideas and desktop research

Then I would A/B test the options with users or people who fit to the users persona and iterate accordingly.